# MySQL generate a column based on if condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables like following

```
User      Advertisement      Payment

id        id                 id
name      title              user_id
address   description        ad_id
                             payment_type
```

For these tables I want to generate a table like below for the logged in users ,regardless of `payment_type`:

```
id    title        is_paid
1     first ad      0 //if not paid
2     second ad     1 //paid
3     third ad      1 
4     fourth ad     0 
5     fifth ad      1
```

So far I wasn't able to do anything as I have no idea how to add an extra column in `mysql`m or to use `if condition` in query.

I'm not asking you to write code for me, but can you let me know what approach to use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can use an `outer join` with a `case` statement:

```
select a.id, a.title, 
    case when p.id is not null then 1 else 0 end is_paid
from advertisement a
    left join payment p on a.id = p.ad_id and p.user_id = 123
```